# Django on Apache with mod_wsgi CSRF Verification Failed

Tags: python, django, apache, csrf

I have a Django site on Apache with mod_wsgi.  At first the admin page would return a 500 error, it started working after restarting Apache and such. But now when I go to log in I get a 403 with this message:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.
```

The only option for CSRF I have in my settings is CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "127.0.0.1"

CSSRF_SECURE_DOMAIN isn't set so it defaults to False.  I am not using https at all currently as the site is still in development.

But I need to be able to access the admin interface.

How can I fix this error?  Everything worked fine on local development servers but once pushed up to a web server I ran into these types of issues.

So does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this CSRF validation error I am having?  And does anyone know how it will change if I got to implement SSL on the site?

All requests/responses are from the same server. Appreciate any help provided.

EDIT:

In my Django logger file output I get this line:

```
[04/Nov/2015 18:13:20] WARNING [django.request:98] Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /sa-admin/login/
```

Saying that the CSRF cookie is not set at all.  But I am using the default contrib.admin to handle all of this so I am perplexed as to the problem.  Only suit has been added to the admin.  But that is just a skin really.

Comment: Did you create your own html template for accessing the admin page?

Comment: @shenk, since you deleted your last question after I'd answered it, you should note that you must restart Apache to reload your code! When you make a change, remember to restart Apache to test. Also, enable DEBUG in your settings so that you don't have to rely on Apache Error Logs.

Comment: No just using the built in admin module

Comment: Is admin the only page that's affected?

Comment: Yes seems to be. But I don't have any other pages that use CSRF for logging in to check that. My forms aren't even completely finished so I can't check those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "127.0.0.1"` from your settings.

Django is looking for CSRF token cookie with your production domain, but won't find it because your application sets `127.0.0.1` as cookie domain due to your settings. So it returns HTTP 403 and logs that cookie is not set.

Comment: Tried to remove it but it didn't seem to make a difference.  Is there something I should replace it with?

Comment: Name of your production domain. If you leave it with "None" it will also work, as it is default value for this setting.

Comment: I had commented it out. So if my production domain is cshenkan.com I should set it to `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'cshenkan.com'` ?  I tried that and I still got the same error.  Also tried setting it to `''` and `None` After I do these changes, do I need to reset Apache in between testing?  Or as I expect, does it not make a difference?

Comment: No, in standard case you should not set this setting at all, leave it as default `None`. Yup, you should restart your Apache. This setting can allow performing POST requests from another subdomains, which is not a standard case. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-domain

Comment: Okay so I will set it back to None.  Since that is the default, can't I just remove the setting completely?  As I said though, when set to None the problem still occurs.

Comment: Yes, you definitely can.

Comment: Well by removing it, and then restarting apache it works now so thanks a ton.  Looks like restarting apache in between is required, I had assumed it wasn't since they were Django changes but seems like it was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94259/discussion-between-maciek-and-shenk).