# Django error: CSRF verification failed only with Apache (not with development server)

Tags: django, apache, csv, mod-wsgi

I have a simple page where the user can select from some list and pressing the submit button can download a csv file generated on the fly according to the selection.

I am following the examples and tutorials provided by the official Django website (Django version 2.1, Python 3.6)

in mytemplate.htm:

```
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'myurl_to_downloadcsvView' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                <input type="radio" name="myname" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ obj.pk }}">
                    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"> {{ obj.name }}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
</div>
```

in views.py:

```
class ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.htm'
    model = mymodel


def downloadcsvView(request):
    blahblah (something I create on the fly)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    for r in blahblah:
        writer.writerow(r)

    return response
```

in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

When I test it with the development server (i.e. manage.py runserver), it works, but when I start the Apache server, when pressing the submit button, I get the error: FORBIDDEN (403) 'CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.' Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set. 
I can "solve" this only by putting @csrf_exempt before the "downloadcsvView".

How can I make it work also with the production server?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534232/4593642

Comment: I did, but I don't have any CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN in my settings.

Comment: Are you using debug=True ? If yes then change it to False to know more about the 403 error

Comment: Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.

Help
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF cookie not set.
    In general, this can occur when there  is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism...

Comment: ...has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies. 
The view function passes a request to the template's render method. 
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL. 
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data. 
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you...

Comment: It seems there is an issue with POST forms. Try changing the form method to GET to see if it works. I only use POST when I have a file to upload so unless you are dealing with files just work with GET

Comment: ...may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.